# Python client can not communicate with ruby server. I get [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, ruby, server, client

I have the intention of running machine learning algorithms written in Python on data in a database of a Ruby on Rails app. After some research I have discovered sockets and therefore created a Ruby server and Python client. I am running them both on two different command prompt terminals.

Here is the Ruby server code:

```
require "socket"

server = TCPServer.open(2000)

loop {
  client = server.accept
  client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
  client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
  client.close
  }
```

Here is the Python client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "localhost"
port = 2000
s.connect((host , port))
```

I do not understand where the problem is. Kindly assist.

Comment: Are boths programs running on  the same host?

Comment: Your code works without problems here.

Comment: but why this awfully complicated approach? Why not just stick to ruby? lif you don't want to use ruby why not just connect to the database direct with python?

Comment: Your machine can have multiple network addresses (Ethernet / Wi-Fi or IPv4 / IPv6), make sure that both are using the same.

Comment: @DisplayName by same host do you mean same computer? If so, then yes. I have both terminals on the same computer.

Comment: @e4c5 I thought of that. I however don't know how to go about accessing the Ruby on Rails app's database with Python. Also I prefer the access be live as users enter data into the database. Kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Stefan How do I do that?

Comment: @TimKabue for example `TCPServer.open('127.0.0.1', 2000)`. In Python, you might have to use `host = "127.0.0.1"` as well.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much! It worked perfectly. I will write the answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

Given insightful answers to my question above the code Ruby server and Python client should be as below.

For the Ruby server:

```
require "socket" # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open("127.0.0.1" , 2000) # Socket to listen on port 2000

loop {                     # Server runs forever
  client = server.accept   # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts(Time.now.ctime) # Send the time to the client
  client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!" 
  client.close # Disconnect from the client

  }
```

For the Python client:

```
import socket # Import socket module

s = socket.socket() # Create a socket object
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 2000 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.connect((host , port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close() # Close the socket when done
```

The open() method of the TCPServer class in Ruby takes two parameters. The first being the host name and the second the port i.e

```
TCPServer.open(hostname , port)
```